# Problems in Restler 3 API Explorer

Tags: php, api, restler

I'm trying to use Restler 3 API Explorer and i'm having some problems. Even though i put "@param int $n1" in the comment, in the API Explorer it shows the parameters as string. Besides that, the API Explorer only shows the "Response Information" when the tag "@return" is set as array. I'd like to know if the problem is with the API Explorer, with my code, or with some configuration.

```
  class Math
  {
     /**
      * Função para somar dois números
      *
      * teste teste teste
      *
      * @param int $n1 teste
      * 
      * @return int
      */
    function add($n1)
    {
      return $n1;
    }
  }
```

(Sorry for the bad english)

Comment: Sounds like you've got an issue with that software package. Which kind of support plans does the vendor offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected in Restler 3 RC4 and the latest Restler API Explorer

Comment: I'd downloaded the version from the http://luracast.com/products/restler, with the last one from the github it worked. Thanks!